# Multiple levels UIView (xib type) not trigger UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to dynamically load some `UIView`s, they're somewhat complex, so I spend few hours made .xib files.

Now let's say I have a `finalView`, which as root/container view presented on screen.
Then I `addSubView(subViewLvOne)`, which also can be a container view.
At last `subViewOne.addSubView(subViewLvTwo)`, now we got everything need.

On screen it's perfect, exactly the result I want to show. `Two` inside `One`, `One` inside `final`.

[image]

But I can not get any click event with `One` and `Two`. It seems `final` got all the events, but since many small subviews inside it, of course I want them to got their own event.

I've simplified my real situation, avoid many irrelevant details, hope now the description is clear.

Any suggestion is welcome, even like "use *** is better than .xib". I myself, already start doubting the direction of this whole solution.

Comment: It should work automatically, when you click view `Two`, `UITapGestureRecognizer` associated with it should be effective.

Comment: have you set your view.userinteractionenabled = true?

Comment: @SaiCYLi Yes, I've tried both true & false , combined with each UIView.

Comment: try 3 different views add 3 different actions to the view controllers, what result did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about 2 hours, I got two tips:

1. the root `UIView` in .xib file, must be large enough.

I have a `UIView` whose width is 200, and a `UIButton` inside it. In runtime, I change the the width constraint of `UIButton` to fill the screen, obviously greater than 200. Then something ridiculous happens: only part of the button can trigger click event. In this case, the width of root `UIView`, i.e. 200 pixel.

2. when `init(frame:CGRect)`, make width and height value large enough.

At first, I copy `CGRect.Zero` from some examples online. My colleague found this will block click event. You can just give a 1000-width and 1000-height, the outside area won't really trigger click event, meanwhile the `UIView` can be tapped correctly.

That's all.